# Is it possible to have a base class method that calls the same (but overridden method) of all it's derived classes?

Tags: c++, oop, design-patterns, inheritance

It's a bit hard to explain in words, so I'll give an example:

*(The following code might have incorrect syntax but it suffices to give an idea)*

```
class A
{
public:
   static void Update(UINT someValue);
};

class B : public A
{
public:
   static void Update(UINT someValue);
};

class C : public A
{
public:
   static void Update(UINT someValue);
};
```

I know static members function do not override each other,
but let's suppose they do.
What I want to achieve, is when `A::Update(someValue);` is called,
It should implicitly call B::Update(someValue), and also C::Update(someValue), as well as call every `static void Update(UINT someValue)` method of other classes derived from A

Is this possible in one way or another?
And if it is, how would you do it?

Comment: It is not possible, and would be contrary to the purpose of OOP. The parent class is unaware of its child classes.

Comment: How will those classes be instantiated?

Comment: @Andres Well, in the case of my code: `Specific_Material spM; Material* pM = &spM;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should be using composite pattern instead. You can read about it at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_pattern and http://www.javacamp.org/designPattern/composite.html

Comment: that's one pretty wild design pattern haha, suits my needs :)

Answer (score 1):

That info below my comment is not enough to have a clear idea about your code but I was thinking if it is possible to do something similar to what C# does with events, where you can register events and the class that triggers then (your base class in that case) can implement a list of function pointers (pointing to the derived methods, which in that case you have to have instances of the derived classes) and call all of then iterating this list. Just an idea, don't know if this is what you need.

Comment: that might be one solution, yes, but atm I'm thinking composite design pattern is the better choice

Answer (score 1):

There's no way to do it automatically. A simple way to get the effect is for each derived class to call the function of its base class:

```
class A
{
  public:
    static void Update(UINT someValue) {
        std::cout << "A\n";
    }
};

class B : public A
{
  public:
    static void Update(UINT someValue) {
        A::Update(someValue);
        std::cout << "B\n";
    }
};
```

If you prefer to work from bottom to top, you could have each class do its work *before* calling the derived class. Of course there's nothing to stop a derived class from implementing `Update` and *not* calling its base class. It is however fine for a class to not implement `Update` at all -- it doesn't care about updates, but its base class's function can still be called. So it's not a huge burden on implementers, they just have to follow the rule that *if* they implement the function, they have to call the base.

Another way might be for the base class to keep a list of "listeners" who are interested in updates, and to call them in turn whenever an update occurs. Each derived class can then register a suitable listener.

It might be difficult to make code like this exception-safe, though, if each level makes changes but one or more levels may throw.